# Avoiding automatic margin set in bootstrap span div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap fluid layout. The layout I desire is as follows:

**My html code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4 well">span4</div>
        <div id="h" class="span8 well ">span8</div>
     </div>
     <div id='calendar' ></div>
</div>
```

It gives `span4` and `span8` column in a row for desktop. On a small device, it puts `span4` at the top and displays `span8` below it. But, when the screen is resized, I wanted to have `span8` at the top and `span4` below it.

**The solution I tried**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="h" class="span8 well pull-right">span8</div>
        <div class="span4 well ">span4</div>
    </div>
    <div id='calendar' ></div>
</div>
```

It works but it gives following layout for big screen. `span4` leaves some margin initially which I want to avoid.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is useless at the moment, but when [Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6342) is released, it will have `.push*` and `.pull*` classes to change the order of columns. From the link: `Add .push* and .pull* modifier classes for easy column source ordering.`

Comment: @Bojangles , i tried to find .push* and .pull* modifier classes for easy column source ordering in http://acmetech.github.io/todc-bootstrap-3/assets/css/todc-bootstrap.css . But, I din get that. Where can  i find it?

Comment: It'll be in Bootstrap **3** when it's released. It's not currently available in the 2.x line

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this style:

```
#x{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

And updating your html to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="h" class="span8 well pull-right">span8</div>
        <div id="x" class="span4 well">span4</div>
    </div>
    <div id='calendar' ></div>
</div>
```

The id is just trumping this portion of the Bootstrap css:

```
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```